# Is there a way to switch workspaces in WebStorm as I have Laptop and Desktop modes

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I work on Webstorm and sometimes work on a small screen (Laptop) and sometimes connect to a multiple desktop screens.
Is there a way to have multiple Workspaces in WebStorm (diff font sizes, diff window locations etc) and easy way to switch between them?

Sean.

Comment: Are you using the jetbrains account sync? Do you use the settings repository?

Comment: yes it is enabled, so how do I set up different configurations? as I am always logged in as the same user.

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93140

Comment: mmm ok too bad, no way to hack it with swapping out file with diff configs for Laptop vs Desktop params?

Comment: You could try to keep two sets of config folders (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and replace them manually.